# PHP Pack - Combining two pack codes like perl does

Tags: php, perl

I've been trying to figure out if the PHP implementation of Pack with statements like this.

In perl this works:

`pack( 'A4/A*', "Humpty-Dumpty" );`

From perl docs:

> Combining two pack codes with a slash (/) associates them with a
>   single value from the argument list. In pack, the length of the
>   argument is taken and packed according to the first code while the
>   argument itself is added after being converted with the template code
>   after the slash.

in php when I try pack something like this getting error:

> Warning: pack(): Type /: unknown format code

and pack return only false.

Have Someone same problems? (or custom code/library to resolve this in php)

Comment: According to the [docs](http://php.net/pack) that isn't supported.

Comment: Yes I kown, just looking for some workaround/library that's can provide this functionality or some advice how to implement it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support perl like pack definitions I implement preprocessing of the definition.